# How is time until transition defined in this lecture note of continuous-time Markov chain?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, definition, markov-chains, markov-process

I'm reading lecture note [Continuous time Markov chains](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ese303/block_3_continuous_time_markov_chains/slides/300_continuous_time_markov_chains.pdf) by Alejandro Ribeiro:

---

Continuous time positive variable $t \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. States $X(t)$ taking values in countable set, e.g., $0,1, \ldots, i, \ldots$. Stochastic process $\{X(t) \mid t\ge 0\}$ on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, \mathbb{P})$ is a continuous time Markov chain (CTMC) if
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \mathbb{P}[X(t+s)=j | X(s)=i, X(u)=x(u), u<s] \\
=& \mathbb{P}[X(t+s)=j | X(s)=i]
\end{aligned}
$$

**Notation:**

- $X[s: t]$ state values for all times $s \leq u \leq t$, includes borders.
- $X(s: t)$ values for all times $s<u<t$, borders excluded.
- $X(s: t]$ values for all times $s<u \leq t$, exclude left, include right.
- $X[s: t)$ values for all times $s \leq u<t$, include left, exclude right.

Homogeneous CTMC if $\mathbb{P}[X(t+s)=j | X(s)=i]$ constant for all $s$. Still need $\mathbb{P}[X(t+s)=j | X(s)=i]$ for all $t$ and pairs $(i, j)$. We restrict consideration to homogeneous CTMCs.

- $T_{i}=$ **time until transition** out of state $i$ into any other state $j$.
- $T_{i}$ is a RV called transition time with cdf
  $$
  \mathbb{P}\left[T_{i}>t\right]=\mathbb{P}[X(0: t]=i | X(0)=i]
  $$

---

I would like to ask how $T_i$ is defined. Is it defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, \mathbb{P})$? If so, what is $T_i (\omega)$ for $\omega \in \Omega$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your transition time is defined on the same probability space. If your process starts a.s. in the point $i$, i.e. $X(0)=i$, it sounds for me to be defined as $$T_i:=\inf\{t>0\mid X(t)\neq i \}.$$

Comment: I'm more interested in the general case where it's not necessarily true that $X(0)=i$. Could you please give the definition of $T_i$ in this case?

Comment: I think there is more information needed, what $T_i$ should be. Since you are considering the whole path, shall it be the time it takes to leave when $X$ is in $i$ for the first time or the second time or...? Otherwise I don't know how it should be defined.

Comment: It sounds weird to me that we have a clear c.d.f function $\mathbb{P}\left[T_{i}>t\right]=\mathbb{P}[X(0: t]=i | X(0)=i]$, but we're not sure how to define it.

Comment: I know it from the discrete time case, that you are usually not interested in $T_i$ but only in its distribution. So it doesn't matter that $T_i$ is only definied for all $\omega$ with $X(0)=i$. You should consider it as a shorter writing of the rhs.

Comment: Yeap, but how $T_i$ is defined is a natural question, is it? :))

Comment: Yes it is definitely. In the lectures I visited, there was only spoken about the rhs and a RV like $T_i$ was never mentioned. So there was never a need to think about the case $X(0)\neq i$.

Comment: Thank you @mag! I'm waiting for a more natural construction of $T_i$.

Comment: @LAD The point is: once you're at $i$, how long will you remain there? So it makes no sense to ask this question when you aren't starting at $i$ yet. There is definitely some abuse of notation going on, but it is not so bad that it can't be understood fairly easily. As for whether $T_i$ is defined on the same probability space, it's sort of the wrong question. It *can* be but it doesn't actually have to be.

Comment: @LAD (Cont.) If you think numerically, you could generate $T_i$ in an entirely parallel thread with entirely separate entropy from the thread that decides the sequence of state occupations. Doing so effectively converts a homogeneous CTMC into a DTMC and some sequences of iid random variables. This is widely done in numerical simulations.